# Is there a way to define a time interval in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to define a time interval and check if `System.DateTime.Now` is within that interval. Is there a way to do that? It seems you can only define a specific time using TimeSpan.

I think I can define two TimeSpan for the start and end of the interval but I think it saves a lot of time if I can just define the interval and use it to compare directly.

Comment: Using `TimeSpan` for start and end sounds very strange. Are you looking for something like "9-10AM every day"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I wouldn't use `DateTime.Now` - you should almost certainly be using `DateTime.UtcNow`, assuming you really want it to be an interval of elapsed time rather than local time. An interval of local time could lead to some really weird behaviour, e.g. if you set it to 01:45 to 02:15 local time, on the day when the clocks go back at 2am...

But beyond that, you could define it to be between two `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` values - I wouldn't use `TimeSpan` for this.

Alternatively, you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which already defines an [`Interval`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Interval.htm) type... (and is, IMO, a better date/time API in general... it would be relatively hard to *accidentally* make the mistake about using local values for the interval using Noda Time, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Just use two DateTimes and check against those.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class like this:

```
class TimeInterval
{
  private DateTime start;
  private DateTime end;
  public TimeInterval(DateTime start, DateTime end)
  {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }
  public bool Contains(DateTime moment)
  {
    return moment >= this.start && moment <= this.end;
  }
}
```

Then just use it like this:

```
var interval = new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 9, 23), new DateTime(2015, 9, 25));
interval.Contains(DateTime.Now);
```

But ensure that all DateTimes you use are of the sime kind (Local, Utc or Unspecified).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't come up with this on my own and I don't remember where I lifted it, but I generally use this construct for this sort of thing:

```
public interface IRange<T>
{
    T Start { get; }
    T End { get; }
    bool Includes(T value);
    bool Includes(IRange<T> range);
}
```

Here is the concrete version for DateTime:

```
public class DateRange : IRange<DateTime>
{
    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public bool Includes(DateTime value)
    {
        return (Start <= value) && (value <= End);
    }

    public bool Includes(IRange<DateTime> range)
    {
        return (Start <= range.Start) && (range.End <= End);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
DateRange range = new DateRange(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));

range.Includes(DateTime.Now);
```

Of course you can use the same interface to define ranges for various types, but DateTime is primarily what I've used it for.